# Update textarea by adding selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

This might be easy but I'm unable to do it. I'm using jQuery datepicker.  There is a textarea in my form, I want to be able to INSERT THE DATE (from the datepicker) TO THE END of the text.

example: 
user types this in the textarea: **I would like my items to be delivered by**

then uses the datepicker and pick select a date : **1/1/2015**

final result should be: **I would like my items to be delivered by 1/1/2015**

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcepp7aj/)

```js
$( "#fieldA" ).datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonText: "Day",
  inline: true,
  altField: '#updateTextField'
});
```

```css
#updateTextField{
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea id="updateTextField">Add date at the end of sentence.</textarea>
<input type="input" id="fieldA" class="datepicker" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: use one of the callbacks datepicker provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another parameter instead of the altField because it overwrites the data and i didn`t see in the  jquery ui documentation how to manipulate it, anyway i edited your script so that the date will be appended to the textarea val using the onSelect parameter.

```
$( "#fieldA" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonText: "Day",
      inline: true,
      onSelect: function() {
          $('#updateTextField').append(' '+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If you`ll want to return a strict value then i'd suggest you to change this line

```
$('#updateTextField').append(' '+$(this).val());
```

to this

```
$('#updateTextField').val('I would like my items to be delivered by  '+$(this).val());
```

Comment: Neat solution, just be aware of appends though. For example if the user selects the wrong date and tries for another then both dates will be appended.

Comment: Yes i agree, if you'll want to return a strict value then i'd suggest you to change `$('#updateTextField').val('I would like my items to be delivered by  '+$(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

Add the onSelect to your datepicker:

```
    $("#fieldA").datepicker(
    {
      showOn: "button",
      buttonText: "Day",
      inline: true,
      altField: '#updateTextField',
      onSelect: function()
      { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
        $("#updateTextField").val("I would like my items to be delivered by " + 
         dateObject.getDate() + "-" + dateObject.getMonth() + "-" + dateObject.getFullYear() );
      }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4j3g86u/